# Error while creating new Play Application using SBT in Windows

Tags: playframework, sbt

I tried to create a new play framework project using sbt using the following command

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

While it is downloading the dependency at the very  end it is throwing the following error

```
Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\yourUserName"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

What actually is the problem here .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error it seems like you don't have git installed in your system. Try to install git (https://git-scm.com/downloads) and generate the project again. It should work for you.